# the vector constructor doesn't change the end_file istream_iterator

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator, istream

i'm studying C++ for C programmers course (coursera) and in module 4 there is an example for how to use istream iterators to load data to STL vector ..but when i tried the code it only printed the **first number** from the file.  i can't find the mistake in the code.

*note :the instructor didn't run the code, he Taught is using PDF. so maybe there something missing in it.*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    fstream data_file("data.txt");

    istream_iterator<int> start_file(data_file), end_file;

    vector<int> data(start_file, end_file);

    int sum = 0;
    for (auto i = start_file; i != end_file; i++)
    {
        sum += *i;
        cout << *i << endl;
    }

    cout << data.size()<<endl;
    cout << sum << endl;
    cout << (sum* 1.0) / data.size() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try enumerating `data.begin()` and `data.end()` in your summation loop rather than the `start_file`  and `end_file`you already used in vector construction. And btw, there is already a function that computes that sum: [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate). As it stands now it seems the only thing you're using that vector for is to get a count, which isn't a very good use for gathering all those numbers.

Comment: we used data.begin() and data.end() earlier in the lesson and he teach another way to do that using the code above.

thanks i will use accumulate in my own code next time, but now i am just trying the code that provided in the course and it didn't work so i need to know why

Comment: You were told why. `istream_iterator` is single-pass. After you pass `start_file` to `vector`'s constructor, you can't use it anymore. The file has been read, and `data` populated with its contents. Is this not what you wanted?

Comment: yes i got it, after i use istream_iterator i will use the data.begin() and data.end() in my loop.

but is using 'istream_iterator' start_file and end_file in for loop like above is totally wrong ?

Comment: It's not wrong to use them in a loop, per se. It's wrong to use `start_file` again (in a loop or otherwise) **after** is has already been used once. The problem is not in *how* you use it, but in the fact that you are trying to use it *twice*.